# User content and infinite scroll

Tags: infinite-scroll

can somebody please tell me how can I get a user submitted content(like a post) and automatically append it at the end when I use infinite scroll.To be more specifically,when I would scroll down and reach the end of the page,I would like the page to get more posts and show them(like facebook with news feed).Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed it's a tableView, fetch more data from server when it reaches the end cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger index = indexPath.row;
    if (index == yourEndCellIndex) {
        [self fetchMoreDataFromServer];
    }
}
```

Fetch server data and append it to you data array.

```
- (void)fetchMoreDataFromServer {
    NSArray *dataFromServer = ....;
    for (id obj in dataFromServer) {
        [self.dataArray addObject:obj];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```